# MySql Group By and Sum total value of other column and then Display in PHP MySQLi Fetch Array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

In theory, I have two columns like so:
[image]

I want the result to be dog 6, and Elephant 2. What I have made so far (and failed [the amount does not get displayed]) is this:

```
$query_check_credentials = "SELECT word, SUM(amount) FROM Data Group By word";


$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_credentials);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ))
            {
                echo $row['amount'];
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `var_dump($row)` to see what's in it? Doesn't that seem like the obvious first step of debugging a problem like this?

Comment: No, I did not think of using that. Yes, it seems to show what I should have wrote (['SUM(amount)']).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give an alias to the sum:

```
SELECT word, SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM Data GROUP BY word
```

and then use `$row['total_amount']`.

If you don't do that, you have to use `$row['SUM(amount)']`